# Django strange icontains behaviour in development

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have been getting some strange behaviour using `icontains` on my development server. I have a complex query which has been returning some strange results (not the expected number). I drilled down to find the problem seems to be with `icontains`.

First off, here is the mysql output of part of the query I want to run in Django:

```
mysql> select * from species where en_name RLIKE 'tortoise';
+-------+----------------------------------+
| id    | en_name                          |
+-------+----------------------------------+
| 16215 | Santa Cruz Galapagos Tortoise    |
| 16214 | Floreana Galapagos Tortoise      |
| 16213 | Volcan Darwin Galapagos Tortoise |
| 16211 | Sierra Negra Galapagos Tortoise  |
| 16210 | Pinzon Galapagos Tortoise        |
| 16209 | Santiago Galapagos Tortoise      |
|   738 | River Tortoise                   |
| 16207 | Volcan Wolf Galapagos Tortoise   |
| 16206 | Pinta Galapagos Tortoise         |
| 16216 | Fernandina Galapagos Tortoise    |
| 16217 | Santa Fe Galapagos Tortoise      |
| 16218 | Alcedo Galapagos Tortoise        |
| 16219 | Cerro Azul Galapagos Tortoise    |
| 16220 | Rabida Galapagos Tortoise        |
+-------+----------------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I drop into the Django shell and run:

```
query_set = Species.objects.filter(en_name__icontains='tortoise')
```

I get a single result:

```
>>> for i in query_set:
...     print i.en_name   
...     
River Tortoise
```

At a guess I would say it is something to do with the number of whitespaces in the `en_name` string (River Tortoise has one whereas the others have >1). I have also heard that `icontains` can behave differently in development and production.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Run this, see what sql is actually being created: >>> print query_set.query

Comment: Beacuse the above is just an an example, if I run print query_set.query then I get a bunch of joins on my real data set. The import part though comes up with `... WHERE `mytable`.`en_name` LIKE %tortoise%`. Shouldn't it be RLIKE?

Comment: Not sure how you'd get LIKE instead of ILIKE, but see my answer for how to get the RLIKE behavior you're looking for

Comment: Only shortest result with lowest Id is showed. Double check for model field `Species.name` lenght and model field `Species.id` type (if it is explicitly declared. Also check for table index. Please: Post both information: model and descr species table.

Comment: It seems to occur just on the development side. On the production server the query runs as expected. Same code, version of Django, and data. The only thing I can think is that there is some discrepancies at the db level. As i mentioned - this is an example and the real data is much more extensive. There could be some FK issues. I guess no-one else has run into a similar problem?

Comment: Best practice is to run the same database software in production, testing, and dev.  That there are idiosyncracies between different DB backends (and even different charactersets in the same backend/storage engine combo) is well documented.  Running a different DB in dev is asking for issues like this one.

Comment: Have you fix your issue? Can you share what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do RLIKE, which to my understanding is an alias of REGEXP  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

```
query_set = Species.objects.filter(en_name__regex='tortoise')
```